# R markdown positioning two frame of same table in a split form side by side

Tags: r-markdown

```
CITY    dist
BLR 2
ABC 10
DEF 4
GHI 22
KQR 16
PNB 10
```

I have this data

I want to display it as in R markdown without headers

---

```
BLR  2      GHI 22
ABC 10      KQR 16
DEF 4       PNB 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove headers from a dataframe with the `unname` function

```
unname(dataframe)
```

Comment: and what for splitting the table